# JQuery how to show, hide divs like scrolling  with mousedown() and mouseup()

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, javascript

Is it possible to show and hide divs like scrolling style with mousedown() from div1 to div5 ?
I have just developed a function which is scrolling down and up. which is working fine.
Can we change this function to show div1, div2.... when `mousedown()` viseversa for `mouseup()` ?

**The thing is that show only one div at a time**

[image]

here is my present JQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var mouseisdown = false;
    $('.up').mousedown(function(event) {
        mouseisdown = true;
      var topVal = $(".content").css("top").replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, ''); //remove the px from the current top val
        topVal = parseInt(topVal);
      console.log(topVal);
      if(topVal < 0){ //This is to stop it when it reaches the top
      $('.up').parents(".container").find(".content").stop().animate({"top":topVal + 20  + 'px'},'slow');
        if (mouseisdown)
    setTimeout(ScrollUp, 400); 
      }
    }).mouseup(function(event) {
        mouseisdown = false;
    });

    $('.dn').mousedown(function() {
        mouseisdown = true;
          var topVal = $(".content").css("top").replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');
        topVal = parseInt(topVal);
      console.log($(".content").height()+ " " + topVal);
      if(Math.abs(topVal) < ($(".content").height() - $(".container").height() + 60)){ //This is to limit the bottom of the scrolling - add extra to compensate for issues
      $('.up').parents(".container").find(".content").stop().animate({"top":topVal - 20  + 'px'},'slow');
        if (mouseisdown)
    setTimeout(ScrollDown, 400);
      }
    }).mouseup(function() {
        mouseisdown = false;
    }); 
});
```

CSS

```
  div.container {
  overflow:hidden;
  width:250px;
  height:200px;
    zoom: 1;  /* IE7 Fix - doesnt work */
  }
  div.content {
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left: 110px; /*this is for demo - it cuts off the text */
    zoom: 1; /* IE7 Fix - doesnt work */
    clear:bothl;
  }
  .up, .dn{
      border:1px solid orange;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .up:hover, .dn:hover{
      background-color:yellow;
  }
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <button class="up">Up</button> &nbsp; 
    <button class="dn">Down</button>
    <hr style="clear:both;"/>

  <div class="content">
     <div id="div1"><p>Dolore magna  aliquam  erat volutpat.</p><p> Suscipit  lobortis  nisl ut aliquip ex ea consequat.</p></div>
     <div id="div1"><p>Suscipit  lobortis  nisl ut aliquip ex</p><p> ea commodo Dolore magna  aliquam  erat volutpat.</p></div>
     <div id="div1"><p>Dolore magna  aliquam  erat volutpat.</p><p>Suscipit  lobortis  nisl ut aliquip ex ea consequat.</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

need to show to show like this here many we can see. I need to show only one div at a time
[similar](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/special_flexible.html)

Comment: The id should be unique as it should be used by JavaScript to select the element in the DOM for manipulation and used in CSS selectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/8HQKR/1/ or with toggling http://jsfiddle.net/8HQKR/3/. Just use jQuery show and hide functions on mouseup and down. You can also use .css('display','none') and .css('display',whatever). Or setting display:none; as a rule in a css class then addClass and removeClass. If you go by adding and removing classes, take a look at .toggleClass.

Comment: Yes something like that. but the thing is that I have more than two divs :(

Comment: As long as you store the index, put the divs into a container, then access the div you want with $("#container:nth-child"+ index + ")", its allright. You have to increment the index as you go along, and make it module of the number of children of the container. Such as var numberOfChildren = $('#container').children().length; and then, (index++) % numberOfChildren. When accessing using nth-child, access it with index + 1, because nth-child is 1-indexed.

Comment: I'd write the code for you but I can't do it right now. If you don't know the selector: http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can. Make it just using [.toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

```
  <div onmouseover="javascrpt: $('#container').toggleClass('active')"> bla bla </div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hqCcx/21/

HTML code:

```
 <div id="_1"><p>Div1 Dolore magna  aliquam  erat volutpat.</p><p> Suscipit  lobortis  nisl ut aliquip ex ea consequat.</p></div>

 <div id="_2"><p>Div2 Suscipit  lobortis  nisl ut aliquip ex</p><p> ea commodo Dolore magna  aliquam  erat volutpat.</p></div>

 <div id="_3"><p>Div3 Dolore magna  aliquam  erat volutpat.</p><p>Suscipit  lobortis  nisl ut aliquip ex ea consequat.</p></div>
```

Javascript code:

```
var scrolldiv = function scrolldiv (par) {

    if (par === "up")
       currentIndex++;
    else
       currentIndex--;

    for (var c  = 0; c < div.length ; c += 1) {
         if (c === currentIndex )
            $("#_"+c).show();
         else
              $("#_"+c).hide();       
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) 

@AntoJs here we have three divs. need show one div at a time. any solution

Comment: First of all never write different div with the same id (id="div1")... now I will try to fix your code.

Comment: I need to show divs like scrolling to next div. is it possible ?

Comment: What do you mean "like scrolling"?

Comment: @webdreamer I can show you image sample in my question.let me upload i. give me 1sec pls

Comment: Well, AntoJs's works, but if you look at my answer, the second js, it will work as well. As long as you hide all the divs you don't want at a time. You could use the $('#container:nth-child'+i+')') selector to iterate through the children adn find the child you want to show, just hide the one you had previously shown. Also, have a container div to position the children divs which you are hiding and showing.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.show()` to show, and `.hide()` to hide.